# overriding a property that has no getter or setter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, getter-setter, setter

My code :

```
class parent(object):
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.val

class child(parent):
    #__init__

    @parent.value.setter
    def value(self):
        return self.get_val()
```

This code is not setting the property value to self.get_val() , instead it is using the old value that is set in the parent.

Here , the parent class has no specific setter method but I need to set the property to a different value in the subclass. How do I do it ? Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: A setter is supposed to actually do the setting, like `self.val = ...`. The return value is not used. Does `self.get_val()` perform assignment? If not, your problem has nothing to do with parent and child classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, the code for your setter is incorrect.

Here is a working solution :

```py
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.val


class Child(Parent):

    @Parent.value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        self.val = val + " overridden"


parent = Parent("initial")
print(parent.value)

child = Child("initial")
print(child.value)
child.value = "new value"
print(child.value)
```

which produces

```
initial
initial
new value overridden
```